# Can't access to ssh after configure OpenVPN Client

Tags: ssh, vpn, iptables

I followed a guide to configure my raspberry to connects to PureVPN server following this guide : [How to Setup PureVPN on Raspberry Pi](https://support.purevpn.com/raspberry-pi-vpn).

I Followed the part regarding OpenVPN. After the configuration I can't access to the Pi through SSH. I removed the installed package and I restored the IP tables but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

### Check SSH

Make sure that your `ssh` server is running properly.

1. Connect to your Pi with a keyboard, mouse and monitor (or other)
2. Check your Pi's `ip address`
   `ip a`
3. Check that `ssh` is running
   `sudo systemctl status sshd.service`
   or
   `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh status`
4. Check that `iptables` is not blocking `ssh` traffic
   `iptables-save`
   (no output is a good sign).

### Undo The Changes

Make sure you undid all of the changes.

1. Uninstall the packages that were installed:
   (If they weren't installed already, of course).

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq openvpn iptables-persistent
   ```
2. Undo the changes to the config files:
   (This step is easy if you backed up your config files before changing them).

   ```
   /etc/dnsmasq.conf
   /etc/openvpn/auth.txt
   /etc/openvpn/server.conf
   /etc/logrotate.conf
   /etc/sysctl.conf
   ```
3. [Undo the changes the `vpn_client_gw_script.fw` script made.](https://github.com/mr-canoehead/vpn_client_gateway/issues)
   (Running scripts that alter your system always carries risks).

### Nuke And Pave

If that doesn't work, reinstalling Raspbian will fix `ssh`.

1. Back up all of your data
2. [Copy a fresh image of Raspbian onto your sdcard](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md)

Comment: Thanks Hydraxan14 for the great tutorial. Unfortunately I can't restore my Pi. I Install again everything. Sorry for the late reply but I was very busy. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Federico  Thanks for letting me know how it turned out!